# Spring Boot Data JPA default configuration and @JsonManagedReference @JsonBackReference

Tags: spring-boot, jackson, lazy-loading, spring-data-jpa, fetch

I use spring boot default configuration. My simple project works correctly with Eager loading type in relation mappings. If i try apply Lazy loading in OneToMany or ManyToMany relation i get a problem than.

They tell problem can be solved if use special annotations to

```
// to mark class field
@JsonManagedReference
@JsonBackReference
// to mark class
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
```

But it does not work because of other problem

```
Hibernate: select projectinf0_.id as id1_4_, projectinf0_.description as descript2_4_, projectinf0_.name as name3_4_ from project_info projectinf0_
2016-07-05 22:32:45 [http-nio-8080-exec-1]                   WARN  o.s.w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver.handleHttpMessageNotWritable(400) - Failed to write HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write content: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.vl.pmanager.domain.model.ProjectInfo.tags, could not initialize proxy - no Session (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.vl.pmanager.domain.model.ProjectInfo["tags"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.vl.pmanager.domain.model.ProjectInfo.tags, could not initialize proxy - no Session (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.vl.pmanager.domain.model.ProjectInfo["tags"])
```

I see, i should fix **failed to lazily initialize a collection of role**. If i have to do something with spring security roles, i have this part in my configuration

```
@Configuration
static class SecurityConfig extends GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void init(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user").password("user").roles("USER").and()
                .withUser("hero").password("hero").roles("USER", "HERO");
    }
}
```

so i can not understand which role collection i should initialize in case if i do not have any relative entities to my corrupted objects.

Comment: Verify that you have **spring.jpa.open-in-view** as true in application.properties. This is exactly the behaviour you would see if it's false (default should be true though)

Comment: i set **spring.jpa.open-in-view** to false. And i believe this behavior can be if no json annotations. But i have added ones

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is in Serialization. Jackson does not know where to stop. For example : if Group has Account and Account has Group (manyToMany), it keeps on serializing in a loop. @JsonManagedReference, @JsonBackReference or @JsonIdentityInfo can do the work, but only from **one direction.** 
What I can suggest is to look into **Spring-data-rest**, along with **Hateoas**. It is much cleaner, and supports bi-directional.

Comment: I do not need manage **Hateoas**. Json should manage lazy loading. If lazy was not loaded collection should be null or empty. If relative collection already loaded it should be shown in json. The annotations provide solution not only for loop but for _lazy problem_ too